# How to assert that the Print dialog box opened, using Laravel Dusk?

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

In Laravel Dusk, you can assert that a dialog box opened, but how can you assert that the print dialog box opened?  There is Javascript that calls window.print(), and I want to test that that code is getting run.

Answer (score 0):

The print dialog isn't a JS dialog in the viewport. The print dialog is part of browser. Dusk is looking at the viewport, and so it doesn't have any functionality at the moment to see the print dialog which opens over the viewport. The current available assertions are listed here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#available-assertions